# Calculate population percentage in javascript calling two different json files

Tags: javascript, lodash, census

I am trying to calculate the percentage of Asian population per county in the United States using Javascript.

To do so, I am calling the data from the Census Api. This is the code I have written so far.

```
  let totalPopulation = await d3.json("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5?get=B03002_001E&for=county:*");
  let asianPopulation = await d3.json("https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5?get=B03002_004E&for=county:*");

  let myMap = new Map();

  Object.keys(totalPopulation).forEach((key) => myMap.set(key, asianPopulation * 100 / totalPopulation));

  return myMap;
```

I know it's wrong but I do not know how to make it work considering that the data is coming formatted this way:

```
[["B03002_004E","state","county"],
["282","28","151"],
["17","28","111"],
["15","28","019"],
["57","28","057"],
["0","28","015"],
["0","28","043"],
["33","28","063"],
```

Ideally, I would like to get an array of objects with a "state"+"county" variable and a percentage variable. If it's possible to keep total population and asian population, that would be great too.

Any thoughts about how to implement this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think simple for loop over the totalPopulation and asianPopulation may give desired results.

```
var percentageAsianPopulationByCounty = [];

for( var i=1; i < asianPopulation.length; i++)
{
  percentageAsianPopulationByCounty.push(
          new Array((asianPopulation[i][0]/totalPopulation[i][0])*100,   asianPopulation[i][1], asianPopulation[i][2] )
)
}
```

Comment: this works great. How could I map percentageAsianPopulationByCounty to get an structure like this {"10001" => 63, "10003" => 32, "10005" => 12, ... }
Thanks cluebit!